# Hide DropDownList in ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu

How to hide DropDownList in ComboBox?

I want use ComboBox only for displaying text.
This control look nice, for me is better than TextBox plus Button.
 So control must be enabled, but without any items.
When user click arrow (or alt + down key) DropDownList should'n show, because ill select value from custom DataGridView in order to fill back text in ComboBox.

**Edit. Alternative solution is set DropDownHeight to 1, with show only 1 pixel line after clicking control.**

**Edit. Real solution. Answer below**

Comment: I think you are going to be better off creating a User Control with a text box and a button. Then adding a Property for the text to show, and a public event for when the button is clicked.

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? Silverlight?

Comment: It sounds like you need a read only text box.

Comment: @WraithNath: As i said, i can do it by TextBox plus Button, but for me this is not answer.

Comment: @jp2code - I don't want TextBox.

Comment: @Revelvice - Ok, I understand you dont want to use a text box but Its not going to be easily acheivable with a ComboBox - you would have to supclass the control and override various events and possibly the paint event to stop the list showing, if that is even possible

Comment: Alternative solution in my post.

Comment: Why do you want a control with a button, if the button doesn't do anything?  I don't understand the requirement.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - User click on button to show DataGridView where he can push back text do ComboBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can intercept the messages that cause the box to drop-down, in a subclass. The following snippet defines a control NoDropDownBox, that ignores the mouse clicks that result in a drop-down of the combo box:

```
public class NoDropDownBox : ComboBox
{
    public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)
    {
        int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        bool handled = false;

        if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            Keys keyCode = (Keys)msg.WParam & Keys.KeyCode;

            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Down:
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(false==handled)
            handled = base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);

        return handled;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {            
        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x201:
            case 0x203:
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's exactly what i need. :) Now i going to simply add event to control in order to handle clik and voilà.

Comment: F4 is also openening combobox dropdown list.

Comment: @Edwin Groenendaal, nice solution, but how to enable combobox back ?

Answer (score 3):

You will have less trouble and create a better end result by simply creating a usercontrol with a textbox and button that is styled in the way you want. If you figure out a way to remove the functionality of the combobox, all you're really doing is creating unneeded complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to create a custom control once and use it any time you do need this functionality.
If you are working with Windows Forms maybe the easiest way is to inherit class UserControl and create your component using the visual designer writing a little code. You can also descend ComboBox class and code your own drawing logic but it seems to be requiring more work.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated]**

OK, you can't set the Combo Box to Read Only, but you can set `Enabled = false`.

I've never tried this, but perhaps you could set the `MaxDropDownItems` to 0.

But, yo'd still set the Combo Box's Text to the value you want in code.

**[Edit]**

Another idea: Set `DropDownHeight` to 0 (...or 1 if it won't accept 0).

Comment: ComboBox don't have ReadOnly properties.

Comment: Updated with another technique. Basically, you're asking for something that is not *cookie cutter*, so you're going to have to force the control to do what you require.

Comment: I can't disable control. Min value of MaxDropDownItems is 1, with in this case do nothing. About DropDownHeight i was writing in my post (alternative solution).

Answer (score 0):

If the *DropDownStyle* is set to **DropDown** and the *Text* is set to "**Something**" then your **ComboBox** won't dropdown when user clicks the button.

At least, I'm getting that behaviour in WinForms (C# 4.0).
Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Even style is DropDown and Text is set, drodownlist will still open.